# Changing source in videos-js eating memory until leak

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-video, jwplayer, video.js

i'm using video-js media player with flash fallback to dynamically play and change mp4-videos (h.264 - only source available) on a site i'm working on.

My problem is, every time i'm changing the video/source, the browser eats more and more memory until it is out of memory and crashes.
the problem occurs on every browser, flash player hardware acceleration enabled and disabled.

Player is initialized like this:

```
            _V_.options.flash.swf = "../Scripts/ThirdParty/video-js.swf";
            _V_.options.flash.iFrameMode = true; //false didn't help
            _V_.players = {};
            _V_("main_video", { "techOrder": ["flash", "html5"] }).ready(function () {

                $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer = this;
                if (!$.b4dvideo.contentInitialised) {
                    $.b4dvideo.contentInitialised = true;
                    $.b4dvideo._loadContent();
                }
                this.on("pause", function () {
                    this.posterImage.show()
                });
                this.on("ended", function () {
                    $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.pause();
                    $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.currentTime(0);
                    $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.pause();
                    this.posterImage.show()
                });
            });
```

And changing the source of the player

```
        if (!$.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.paused()) {
            $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.pause();

        }
        $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.currentTime(0);
        $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.pause();

        $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.src(videoPath);

        $.b4dvideo.videoPlayer.play();
```

It looks like the flash player is keeping the whole video in memory and never releasing it.
Any ideas on that?
I have even tried using jwplayer - same problem :-(

**Update 1:**

I also created a js-fiddle demonstrating this issue... just press play several times and watch your memory
http://jsfiddle.net/fwcJh/2/

Comment: Where is an example with the JW Player?